# execvp function working without path

Tags: c, shell, exec

i am writing a running shell script with C programming. I have read about exec function although didn't understand much but I have read an example in which execvp is used like this

> execvp(*argv, argv) ;
>
> /* here argv is a char pointer array containing commands like ls -l
>
> argv[0]-> ls
>   argv[1]-> -l
>
> */

but it is used without giving file name as argument i idn't get it how it is working then . any one can please explain this as in the description it of execvp it is given to specified file name
thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

In your case where you are actually passing 
Arg1: `ls`
Arg2: `ls` `-l`
After ensuring that your arguments are not NULL, this check is done

```
/* If it's an absolute or relative path name, it's easy. */
if (strchr(argv[0], '/')){
    execve(argv[0],argv,environ);
}
//In your case this would fail because argv[0] is not an absolute path.
//So now the search for argv[0] begins in the PATH
path = getenv("PATH")
//Now for each directory specified in path, it will attempt an execve call as
//For simplicity, I am calling each directoryname in PATH to be dir
execve(strcat(dir,argv[0]),argv,environ)
//If this generates an error called [ENOEXEC][1], then it's okay to continue searching in other directories, else quit searching and return the errorcode
```

I have provided a simplified and abstract view of execvp's working. You must look through the source code to understand the internal workings better